# how MD5 signature affects the app security?

Tags: android, security, md5

I am planning to integrate a paid 3rd party SDK to my app. For that, 3rd party team asked to share my app package name and MD5 signature of app (Which is generated using another app provided by 3rd party company). I just want to know whether sharing the MD5 signature of my app affects the security of my app/code? Can somebody help me to get an idea on this?

Comment: Generally it's not a good idea to go on using MD5 as it's not secure anymore, although, for an app signature, i don't think i lessens very much (at all?) an android app code security by itself, as .apk files are basically just a .zip of your java files. The hazardous part IMO is if you have to deliver all your code to a 3rd party app before you release it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MD5 was intended to provide integrity, not security. MD5 is a checksum, so It is supposed to be a short representation of potentionally infinite data. If you have a 1GB file, create an MD5 hash of it and flip a single bit within the 1GB file, the MD5 completly changes.

You will need the 1GB file, to calculate the MD5, you cannot get the 1GB file from the MD5.
I write intended since MD5 is concidered broken, an attacker could potentionally create content that is aimed to produce the same MD5.

Answer (score 1):

No. MD5 is just hash (one way) function. It won't expose anything but the hashing result. Sharing it or making public poses any threat to your app/code.